# How to submit html input in code c sharp?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have some HTML input fields that I want to use in asp.net code (i.e. in code behind code - C#).

This is my code :

```
<form id="contact_form" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label for="name" >Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text"   />
        <span id="nameinfo">what's your name?</span>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: This is not a specific question. There are plenty of tutorials on how to submit and process html form data using c#.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

Add a name to your input like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
```

Then you can read the posted value in C#:

```
string name = Request.Form["name"];
```

Solution 2:

If you are using Web Forms, replace the input with an asp:TextBox control like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="tbName" runat="server" />
```

And the you can read the posted value using:

```
string name = tbName.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the id as the name in your .cs file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

> runat="server"

in your HTML input for eg:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" runat="server" value="" />
```

then you can use it in code behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input1.Value = "Welcome";
}
```